# Need clarification on apache reload

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I need to do a `/etc/init.d/httpd reload` on my production server running `httpd`. Was wondering if after doing the configuration changes if there is some configuration glitch and we do a reload , will `apache` will fail .  Or the server will ignore the request and there will be no `reload` .

Please clarify.

Comment: do you have a test system?

Comment: no  :( ....that's why I post this to this group.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html

Comment: also, consider setting up a test system, or a config file that points to an unused port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested on RHEL 6.6**

If you're worried about glitches, or errors in your configurations, you can always run

```
/etc/init.d/httpd configtest
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -t
```

before `reload` -- a good habit IMHO. A `reload` does not stop your running processes if you have errors in your configuration, and keeps the current processes running. A `restart` will stop the `httpd` processes and **then** try a start, and fail if there are configuration errors. For more details, examine the relevant lines from the `/etc/init.d/httpd` script.